# Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib

Tags: homebrew

When I enter the command  brew doctor I get the error below. This this something to worry about?

Im very new to command line stuff. Im using homebrew to install Drush (for Drupal).

```
Last login: Wed Oct  9 14:59:40 on ttys001
unknown:~ MY-USERNAME$ brew doctor
Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libTrAPI.dylib
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

These files, in your case only one, is an residual files from older installations. Nothing to worry about.

You can easily remove it with:

```
rm /usr/local/lib/libTrAPI.dylib
```

Comment: this is a horrible answer, consider Brian Carlsons answer.

Comment: You could try to move the file elsewhere and wait to see if something breaks. `mv /usr/local/lib/libTrAPI.dyli ~/Desktop/`

Comment: To elaborate on @scravy , the reason this is a horrible answer is that by deleting them, you may break something.  Unfortunately, not *everything* you have on your machine has been installed by Homebrew nor can everything be installed via Homebrew.  `brew doctor` itself states, effectively, that you should try to clean up what you can, and ignore warnings that you cannot easily fix.  This is because Homebrew knows they cannot be responsible for everything on your machine.

Answer (score 25):

libTrAPI.dylib is for your VPN software. If you want to continue to use your VPN, don't delete it, just add it to the whitelist in doctor.rb and then homebrew won't complain about it.

To find your doctor.rb simply run

```
locate doctor.rb
```

Look for white_list, mine was on line 105. It should probably look like this.

```
white_list = {
  "libfuse.2.dylib" => "MacFuse",
  "libfuse_ino64.2.dylib" => "MacFuse",
  "/usr/local/lib/libTrAPI.dylib" => "TrAPI"
}
```

Comment: A few lines stating how to add a file to the whitelist would make this a much better answer.

Comment: My locate wasn't updated on my mac 10.9. I found mine was here;  /usr/local//Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb .

Comment: It then warns about the edited file; "Warning: You have uncommitted modifications to Homebrew
If this a surprise to you, then you should stash these ....    cd /usr/local/Library && git stash && git clean -d -f"

Comment: Be careful to look for `white_list`. If you accidentally omit the underscore and search for `whitelist` instead, you'll find something completely different.

Comment: @Anne, the commands `brew doctor` suggest will undo your change. If it's a change you want to keep, though, then you can commit it instead: `git add /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb`, then `git commit -m 'Tell brew doctor to ignore libTrAPI.dylib'`.

Comment: @Rob thank you! I had read about committing previously but was confused because I didn't see the repo. I should have just done a git status, indeed there it is. I found the /.git/ folder two levels up, at /usr/local/.git, which really surprised me since I thought other apps could use this folder?

Comment: [As of 2016](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/pull/47665/commits), the whitelist now resides in /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/diagnostic.rb.

Comment: Note: As of https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/7703/ the list has been renamed to `allow_list`. As of my current version of brew (`3.5.9-102-g4027c62`) it is line `222` of `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/diagnostic.rb`

Comment: This seems to be a temporary fix. Even if I commit these changes, when brew is updated, that commit is thrown away.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently working with a custom SQLite3 extension (https://github.com/vlcn-io/cr-sqlite). After placing the required `crsqlite.dylib` into `/usr/local/lib`—the *only* user-writable path that SQLite searches by default when issuing the `.load` command, I found myself facing this `brew doctor` spew problem.

I found the hardcoded `allow_list` array inside `diagnostic.rb` (https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/diagnostic.rb#L200), but couldn't find any user-definable config file or supported method of customizing this list (other than editing the file directly, which was subject to being overwritten by updates).

**The solution I came up with** was to create a shell wrapper function around sqlite3, which exports the `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` variable. This allowed me to place the dylib in a subfolder, which prevents Homebrew from complaining about it.

e.g. in your `.bash_profile`, `.zshrc` etc

```shell
sqlite3() {
  export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/sqlite3
  /opt/homebrew/opt/sqlite/bin/sqlite3 "$@"
}
```

The dylib can then be placed into `/usr/local/lib/sqlite3/`:

[image: dylib location]

A similar solution might be applicable to other programs, although it might not work in all cases. You can also try exporting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` if the fallback path isn't honored.